# java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() with ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run a ListActivity, which takes an array of filenames, which are to be inserted into the database. This is done by `insert()` in the following code. I am getting IllegalStateException at `ArrayAdapter<String>`. If I am calling the `insert()` function from another class. So, I am unable to define ArrayAdapter in the `onCreate()` method. Please see the following code, which is defining `insert()` method -

```
public class FileEvent extends ListActivity implements ObserverActivity{
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

public String filename;
public String path; 
MyFileObserver myFileObserver; 
public adapter info ;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarr;
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   this.info  = new adapter(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    setContentView(R.layout.fileeventlist);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    myFileObserver = new MyFileObserver("/storage/sdcard/DCIM/SAMPLE_IMAGES/");
        myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
        myFileObserver.startWatching();

/*  String var_from_prev_intent = bundle.getString("path");
    insert(var_from_prev_intent);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences (PREFS_NAME,0);
    String newpath = "";
    this.path = settings.getString("name",newpath);
    Log.v("New path in FileEvent : ",this.path);*/

}

 protected void onPause(){
        myFileObserver.stopWatching();
        myFileObserver.unregisterObserver(this); 
      } 

      protected void onResume(){
        myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
        myFileObserver.startWatching();
      }
public void insert(String path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
Log.v("FileName to insert : ",path);
Log.v("a3","a3");
this.info = new adapter(this);
this.filename = path; 
Log.v("a4","a4");
if(info == null)
{
    System.out.println("info is null here.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("info is not null here.");
}
int rowcount = info.getrowcountofpersons(); 
Log.v("a5","a5"); 
Log.v("rowcount in new list onCreate: ", ""+info.getrowcountofpersons()+"");
Log.v("a6","a6");
String[] values = new String[rowcount];
Log.v("a7","a7");
for(int i =1;i<=rowcount;i++)
{
    values[i-1]=info.getPersonList(i); 
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[i-1],  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("in for loop now"+values[i-1]);
} 
Log.v("a8","a8");


 adapterarr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values); 
Log.v("a9","a9");

Log.v("a10","a10");
listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
Log.v("a11","a11");
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
Log.v("a12","a12");

// Assign adapter to List
setListAdapter(adapterarr);  
//  new Bullet(info).execute((Void)null);
Log.v("a13","a13");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        Log.v("Error in insert() definition FileEvent.java : ",e.toString());
    }
    }


protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

//  try{
    Log.v("a14","a14");

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.v("a15","a15");
      // ListView Clicked item index
       int itemPosition     = position;
       Log.v("a16","a16");
      // ListView Clicked item value
       String  itemValue    = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
       Log.v("a17","a17");
     //  content.setText("Click : \n  Position :"+itemPosition+"  \n  ListItem : " +itemValue);
       String personname = itemValue;
       Log.v("a18","a18");
       try
       {
           System.out.println("paths in FileEvent : "+filename);
           info.insert(filename,personname);
           Log.v("a19","a19");
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Log.v("a20","a20");
           e.printStackTrace();
           Log.v("a21","a21");
       }

       Log.v("a22","a22");
/*  }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("Error in insert() definition FileEvent.java : ",e.toString());
    }

*/   

}
```

And the following logcat I am getting, when I run the code -

```
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284): Unhandled exception in FileObserver com.example.sample_fileobserver.MyFileObserver@b11955a0
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4492)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileEvent.insert(FileEvent.java:76)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at com.example.sample_fileobserver.MyFileObserver.onEvent(MyFileObserver.java:59)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:125)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
09-27 06:37:23.269: A/FileObserver(2284):   at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)
```

Please tell me where I made mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: initialize info inside onCreate

Comment: have you added permission in manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your code to OnResume method.

Comment: @Naeem A. Malik, I cannot do that, because I am calling `insert()` from another class.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do `public adapter info = new adapter(this);` before onCreate. Initialize that into onCreate.

Like

```
public adapter info; // Removed  = new adapter(this);
```

and in `onCreate` method do like this

```
info = new adapter(this);
```

---

And another suspect that

```
public adapter info = new adapter(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

I am very sure that this will not compile. So verify it.

Comment: No @Pankaj Kumar, When I remove `public adapter info = new adapter(this);`, some other functions, which are using the `info` variable are becoming null. So cannot do that.

Comment: @nki Yes you are right. Thats why I removed that line from answer :) . What is adapter? If this class then change  `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter` to `ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter` and all occurance of this adapter.

Comment: yes that is a class. Should I keep the same names? Sorry that I don't know using an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I have changed the ArrayAdapter `adapter` to `adapterarr`. But also getting the same exception.

Comment: DO one thing rename the `adapter` class with `Adapter`. In java class name starts with capital. And then initialize that into onCreate as I answered.

Comment: why should I change the class name?

Comment: :D :D You have to change name of variable from those two lines, right? Then I said to change class name because this was about naming conversion. Nothing more. So choice is your either change name of array adapter or class name.

Comment: In your updated code you chnaged name of array adapter.. BUT the code `final adapter info = new adapter(this);` is as it is. I said move that code to oncreate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38169/discussion-between-nki-and-pankaj-kumar)